# How to de-escalate social situations while standing my ground?

Tags: conflict-aversion, de-escalation

#### Context:

I was at the gym today, and doing some squats. I sometimes grunt a bit loudly when I do 'em, and some people laugh when I do that (I don't really care about this). When I went to fill up my water bottle later, one guy came to me, held my wrist, and told me to "Stop making stupid noises when you squat". I immediately went off on this guy, and told him "when you insult someone at the beginning of giving advice, it will turn the confrontation emotional, and no one will take you seriously". He then told me to "calm down", to which I replied, "I come to the gym to do exercises, not to put an exhibition for other people".

After some back and forth of repetitions, I went back to do more squats, he started doing some other exercises near me. He looked at me, so I said (nicely), "you want to squat?" He got angry and started saying that he'd kill me if I ever shouted at him again (I get a bit loud when I am angry), and in general, kept escalating the situation.

Ultimately, the gym instructors got involved and the situation was solved by us being separated.  I left the gym and came back 20 minutes later to complete my workout.

---

How could I have tackled this scenario without escalating? It seems to me, that if I weren't to escalate with my tone, then I'd have been seen as a push over, and that I wouldn't be ever squat seriously again (I can't control the grunt noise when I squat (believe me I searched many times on the internet how to reduce it).

---

#### Note

Death threats in itself would have been reason for that guy to have been kicked from the gym if I were in any lawful land, but I live in a place where in-house rules take more precedence than anything else.

#### Question:

How do I de-escalate this type of social situation *while standing my ground*?

Comment: Normally I'd say if someone comments on how you exercise it's best to ignore the comments.  Did the guy actually grab your arm?  And that was the start of the conversation?

Comment: Yes that was @DaveG

Comment: In the US I would say to just nod or something, and then go report this guy to whoever is running the gym. Otherwise, I would focus on remaining calm and polite even if the other guy is yelling.

Comment: "I immediately went off on this guy" and that is how you started escalating things.

Comment: @KCWong well, the other guy started by grabbing his arm.  When a stranger starts a "conversation" by getting physical it's pretty hard to avoid escalation.

Answer (score 2):

Stay calm at all times. If someone tells you something inapropriate, never raise your voice or insult.

> "when you insult someone at the beginning of giving advice, it will turn the confrontation emotional, and no one will take you seriously".

Your reaction would have been totally fine if you kept it calm. But when you raise your voice, you become the one at fault. Now your adversary can point fingers at you: "This guy yelled at me!".

I don't think you would seem like a "pushover" if you remain calm. I think it's a show of a strong character if someone can smile at a bully and say "have a nice day".

Answer (score 0):

Best way to avoid escalation is not getting involved at all. My personal response to a situation like this would be completely ignore that person's existence and mind my own business.
That being  said if you do have to respond in any way make sure you keep your voice controlled and say something short that's not against the other person. As an example,

> Guy: Stop making stupid noises when you squat.

> Me: Yeah.

This will ensure the guy has nothing else to say.